# Update dynamically created textbox

Tags: c#, mysql

I have created this update function but I am gettng "SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized" error.Can anyone help me for this.My code is:

```
   public  void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;
        b.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        b.Font.Bold = true;
        string strTableName = Request.QueryString["table"];
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtColumn=new DataTable();
        MySqlConnection sQLcONN = new MySqlConnection("connection");
        sQLcONN.Open();
       // MySqlCommand sqlcolum=new MySqlCommand("SELECT *FROM   information_schema.columns WHERE  table_name ="+strTableName);
       // MySqlDataAdapter sqlDa1=new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlcolum);
       // sqlDa1.Fill(dtColumn);
       // MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("update " + strTableName + "set " + dtColumn.Rows[introws]["column_name"] + "='" + "txtTextbox" + dt.Rows[introws][0].ToString() + "' where " + dtColumn.Rows[introws]["column_name"] + "=" + dt.Rows[introws][0], sQLcONN);
         MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("update " + strTableName + "set " + dtColumn.Rows[introws]["column_name"] + "=@value1  where " + dtColumn.Rows[introws]["column_name"] + "=@value2", sQLcONN);

sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", "txtTextBox + dt.Rows[introws][0].ToString()");
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2",dt.Rows[introws][0]);
        MySqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);


        sqlDa.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Write("Succesfully updated");
        }
        else
        {

            Response.Write("Error");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: where have u created the textbox?

Comment: I have created the textbox in another function..

Comment: have u initialized that textbox globally?

Comment: the error seems to be with the connection instead of text box
also do not include sensitive information when u post ur code
u can use XYZ or other meaningless text

Comment: I think you dont need that MySqlDataAdapter at all. Just remove it and call sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery method to update rows into database.

Comment: This line seems to have a problem as I think it should not be enclosed in double quotes:
"txtTextBox + dt.Rows[introws][0].ToString()"

Comment: "There is no row at position 0".Now I am getting this error..

Comment: @user3079437  Because your `datatable` is empty , where have you populating your datatable.

Comment: Yes I populate data but now I am getting mysql syntax error as this "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '5='N5'  where 5=5' at line 1".